# redirect from another module (Flask)

Tags: python, opencv, flask

So I have a opencv flask camera streaming code. The function generating the frame to be streamed is outside `app.py`. I want to be able to automatically stop the stream and redirect to `page2` when an event happens. I tried to do it in  `@app.route('/video_feed')` as the code below shows. I spent two days with no results.

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, redirect, url_for, 
import cv2
from applogic import AppLogic

app = Flask(__name__)
vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
applogic = AppLogic()


@app.route('/')
def index():
    """Video streaming home page."""
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/page2')
def page2():
    """the page to be redirected to when event happens."""
    return render_template('page2.html')


@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    """Video streaming route. Put this in the src attribute of an img tag."""
    temp = applogic.gen()
    if temp != 1
        return Response(applogic.gen(),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
    else: 
        return redirect(url_for('page2'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1]', debug=True, threaded=True)
```

applogic.py (please mind the indentation):

```
import cv2

class AppLogic:

def __init__(self):
    self.checkx = True
    self.vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def gen(self):
    while True:
        if self.foo():
            rval, frame = self.vc.read()
            cv2.imwrite('t.jpg', frame)
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + open('t.jpg', 'rb').read() + b'\r\n')
        else:
            return 1

def foo(self):
    # some logic that returns True or False
    return True
```

index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Video Streaming Demonstration</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Video Streaming Demonstration</h1>
    <img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">
  </body>
</html>
```

page2.html: has a normal html "hello world" code; nothing special

Thank you.

Comment: Your code used to redirect (i.e. `redirect(url_for('page2'))`) seems correct.

Comment: @GreyLi doesn't work because `video_feed` is being called from html `<img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">`. When `gen()` return `1`; the app freezes

Comment: Seems like its really a problem since no solutions till now. All what we are trying to do is to call redirect based on some event that happens outside `app`